# Is the cyclic permutation $(1 2 3)$ equal to $(12)$ followed by $(13)$ or $(13)$ followed by $(12)$

Tags: permutations

At the bottom of this page: http://dogschool.tripod.com/permgroups.html it states that

> (1 2 3) This is equivalent to two transpositions: (1 2) followed by (1 3) [try it!]

So I did try it: ( 1 2 3 ) means that 1 goes to 2 which goes to 3 which goes to 1. So if we apply this to the list: 1 2 3, we should get 3 1 2.

Now if we do ( 1 2 ) followed by ( 1 3 ) onto the list 1 2 3:

1 2 3

Apply ( 1 2 )

2 1 3

Apply ( 1 3 )

2 3 1

Clearly this is not 3 1 2 so doesn't that mean that ( 1 2 3 ) =/= ( 1 2 ) followed by ( 1 3 )

In fact if I try ( 1 3 ) followed by ( 1 2 ):

1 2 3

Apply ( 1 3 )

3 2 1

Apply ( 1 2 )

3 1 2

If would seem that ( 1 2 3 ) is equivalent to ( 1 3 ) followed by ( 1 2 )

Is this website wrong? Or am I mistaken about something?

Comment: If you apply (123) to the list 1,2,3 you should get 2,3,1.

Comment: There are different conventions for composing permutations. The one I was first taught seems to be in the minority these days. You just need to be clear whether the operative convention is right-to-left or left-to-right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that they do permutation multiplication from left to right (I do it/learned it right to left).

So from left to right, it should be
$$(1\;2\;3) = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
2&3&1
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
2&1&3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
3&2&1\end{pmatrix}=(1\;2)(1\;3)
$$
So it appears that they are right when they say $(1\;2)$ followed by $(1\;3)$.

---

I believe it works like this

[image]

So from left to right, $(1\;2)(1\;3) = (1\;2\;3)$.

Comment: I was using left to right but I am still confused.

Doesn't $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\2 & 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ mean that 1 goes to position 2. But if you do $(1 3)$ last then one ends up in position 3?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. It would help if you wrote it out. $(1\; 3) = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\3&2&1\end{pmatrix}$. So yes, $3\leftrightarrow 1$, but this is before you multiply; after you multiply $1\rightarrow 2$. Am I answering your question?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\2 & 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

So does this mean that 1 goes to position 2 or does it mean that 1 goes to position three?

Comment: That array by itself means $1\to 2, 2\to 3, 3\to 1$.

Comment: So when if we did $(12)$ the one ends up in position 2, but after we apply $(13)$ then the one ends up in position 3. 

But then if we do $( 1 2 3 )$ the one should end up in position 2 not three. So clearly doing $( 1 2 3 )$ is not equal to doing $(1 2)$ and then $(1 3)$. In the former the one ends up in position 2, in the latter the one ends up in position 3.

Comment: I see, by 'doing' you mean multiplying. $(1\;2\;3)$ is not  'doing' anything in the sense that it is being multiplied to anything (unless you say the identity permutation. Let $\sigma = (1\;2), \tau = (1\;3)$. Then 'doing' $(1\;2)(1\;3)$ is a product of $\sigma$ and $\tau$.

Comment: And the product is $\sigma\tau = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
2&3&1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: So what exactly does a permutation array mean? I thought it was an operation that could be carried out on a list of numbers. I thought I could apply $( 1 2 3 )$ to a list of numbers. If not then what does $( 1 2 3 )$ actually represent if it can't "do" anything?

Comment: No, I'm saying you are confusing two things (I think). Yes a permutation (array) by itself "moves" elements around. But when talking about ***multiplication***, $\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
2&1&3\end{pmatrix}$ doesn't mean anything. You need to multiply it to something else. So in terms of ***multiplication***, $\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
2&1&3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
3&2&1\end{pmatrix}$ does mean something, it means multiply $\tau$ by $\sigma$. Is that ok?

Comment: I see but based on my computations I can't see how $στ$ is equal to $(1 2 3 ) $(left to right)

I am saying $τσ$ is equal to $( 1 2 3 )$ (Still left to right)

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Ooooooh I see now what I was doing wrong. In the first permutation, 1 would be the first, 2 would be the second, and 3 would be the third. But of course, it changes once you do the first permutation. So in after $(1 2)$, when I did $(1 3)$ I was swapping the numbers one and three, but I should be swapping the numbers in positions 1 and 3, which is 2 and 3.

Comment: Great. I'm glad you got it. Consider up voting and giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck.